# A question on the Prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, prime-factorization

Let $N\geq1$. Could we infer $$\sum_{n\leq N}\mu(n)\ll N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N})$$from $$\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n)= N+O(N\exp( -c\sqrt{\log N})$$or $$\sum_{p \leq N}1=Li(x)$$ without resorting to the Vaughan's identity (Perhaps, the Vaughan's identity does not wok. The factorization of primes seems plausible)? Here $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function.

Further let $N\geq1$ and any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $a(n)$ be the $n$th normalized Fourier coefficient of a primitive holomorphic or Maass cusp form for $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Could we infer $$\sum_{n\leq N}\mu(n) a(n)e(n\alpha) \ll_f N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N})$$from $$\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda(n)a(n)e(n\alpha)\ll_f N\exp( -c\sqrt{\log N})$$or $$\sum_{p \leq N}a(p)e(\alpha p)\ll_f N\exp( -c\sqrt{\log N})$$ 'directly' as above? Here $$\sum_{n\leq N}\mu(n) a(n)e(n\alpha) \ll_f N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N})$$ has been given by Fouvry and Ganguly. (c.f. Strong orthogonality between the Mobius function, additive characters,
and Fourier coefficients of cusp forms)

I really wish someone to help me out, and any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the last sum, are you only summing over primes? Is there any reason the variable is $p$ rather than $n$?

Comment: yes, the sum over $p$ is equivalent to ths sum involving $\Lambda(n)$

Comment: What sort of inference are you looking for? All three are equivalent (more or less) to the classical zero-free region for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @Greg Martin  sorry Martion. There are something incorrect in the post, I have rectified.

Comment: Your first equation has a typo: the right-hand side should be $O(N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N}))$, not $N + O(N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N}))$. Also the right-hand side of the third equation should be $\mathrm{Li}(N) + O(N\exp(-c\sqrt{\log N}))$.

Comment: The first three equations have nothing to do with Vaughan's identity, which is really only relevant when you're dealing with exponential twists. @GregMartin is right; the first three equations are just equivalent statements about a zero-free region for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Thanks for Peter Humphries. I found my answer from H. Iwaniec and
E. Kowalski's book. Definitely we can infer the sum $\sum_{n\le N}\mu(n)$ directly from $\sum_{n\le N}\Lambda(n)$. Ses Corollary 5.29 of the book.